# Connection to Googleapis.com Refused

Tags: c, sockets, https, google-geolocation, zephyr-rtos

I am developing an embedded c application on the nrf9160 dev kit.

My goal is to use the googleapis.com/geolocation service to provide location data for my system, but I have been unable to do so.

I have created a billing account on the google cloud platform, created an api key, and created and attempted to use a variety of https Certificates using the Certificate Authority Service, but I am unable to connect.

Whenever I call the connect() function to attempt to connect to googleapis.com, I get a "Connection Refused" error.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
err = cert_provision();
if (err) {
    printk("getaddrinfo() failed, err %d\n", errno);
    return;
}

((struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr)->sin_port = htons(HTTPS_PORT);

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TLS_1_2);
if (fd == -1) {
    printk("Failed to open socket!\n");
    goto clean_up;
}

/* Setup TLS socket options */
err = tls_setup(fd);
if (err) {
    goto clean_up;
}

printk("Connecting to %s\n", "googleapis.com");
err = connect(fd, res->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (err) {
    printk("connect() failed, err: %d\n", errno);
    goto clean_up;
}
```

Note: I have been able to connect to google.com and github.com using certificates specific to those sites.

Help resolving this issue would be very appreciated.

Comment: Which OS is this? What is HTTPS_PORT? Connection refused usually means that the server is not listening on the port.

Comment: HTTPS_PORT = 443.

This system runs on Zephyr.

Comment: It seems Zephyr has specific socket functions, such as [`zsock_socket()`](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/networking/sockets.html#c.zsock_socket). You are probably using the POSIX variants of these functions or mixing both variants. POSIX `socket()` does not support `IPPROTO_TLS_1_2`.

Comment: It is a wrapper function defined by the nordic SDK i am using with the board that uses the zsock functions.

As I mentioned, I was able to use the exact same method of connection to get responses from google and github, with the only thing changing being the target website and the certificate.

Is there a specific type of certificate i need to provision myself? I tried half a dozen different options in the certificate creator but none of them worked.

Comment: Hello, I am pushing this again to see if it gets any more traction. I have not been able to resolve this issue.